# Windows 7 DWM weirdness

Tags: c#, api, screenshot, task, dwm

I'm looking to write a FOSS "Alt+Tab" replacement (window switcher) for Windows, since there are a few features I feel it's (still) lacking; but I'm noticing two quirks I can't seem to fix:

#1. (Somewhat Unrelated) In the default Windows 7 window switcher, one computer allows **left** clicking on a thumbnail to focus the window; however on another, similarly specced computer, I have to use a **right** click. The only difference between these two fresh installs is the theme. Any ideas?

#2. (Directly Related) In both the default Windows 7 window switcher *and* the DWM API output, minimized windows often have no thumbnail, and instead show only the taskbar. This has been a long running problem with the Windows API, and in the past I've seen the popular recommendation being "restore (un-minimize) the window, take a screenshot, then re-minimize" - but this is sloppy and causes flickering, etc. Has anyone done this successfully using the newer DWM API?

If sharing code, I'd prefer C# syntax, but VB.NET will do as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is similar to a question i asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848558/dwm-what-api-to-create-applications-like-flip3d), but starting from a different place. i *assume* Microsoft is using an internal, undocumented, API to power the Flip3D, which is why it has access to the screenshot of minimized windows.